# DataFrame to list of lists

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `DataFrame` `df` with several `columns`, including expiry and iv. I would like to create a `lol` = `list-of-list [[]]` so that each row in the `lol` corresponds to a given expiry. For example, say `df` look like this:

```
df =


expiry             iv
===========================
2019-01-18,        .18
2019-01-18,        .17
2019-01-18,        .16
2019-02-18,        .14
2019-02-18,        .13
2019-02-18,        .12
```

**the `lol` would look like this**:

```
lol = [
[0.18, 0.17, 0.16],
[0.14, 0.13, 0.12]]
```

So each row of the `lol` would correspond to the corresponding date in the `df`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
LoL=df.groupby('expiry').iv.agg(list).tolist()
LoL
[[0.18, 0.17, 0.16], [0.14, 0.13, 0.12]]
```